# Chapter title under chapter number in KOMA class

Tags: chapters, koma-script, scrbook

Using the `scrbook` class, how do I place the chapter title under the chapter number? Here's a MWE

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{xcolor, graphicx}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\definecolor{chaptergrey}{rgb}{0.7,0.7,0.7}

\let\raggedchapter\raggedleft
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\normalfont}
\setkomafont{chapter}{\LARGE}

\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
\scalebox{5}{\color{chaptergrey}\thechapter}%
}
\begin{document}
\chapter{A chapter}
\end{document}
```

The corresponding output is

[image]

And what I'd like to have is something like this

[image]

Once I can do that, how do I change the vertical space between the two?

EDIT:

```
\documentclass[chapterprefix]{scrbook}
\usepackage{xcolor, graphicx}
\definecolor{chaptergrey}{rgb}{0.7,0.7,0.7}

\let\raggedchapter\raggedleft
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\normalfont}
\setkomafont{chapter}{\LARGE}

\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
\scalebox{5}{\color{chaptergrey}\thechapter}%
}

%\makeatletter
%\renewcommand{\@chapapp}{}
%\makeatother

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\fancypagestyle{theorems}{
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{##1}{}}
\fancyhead[LO, RE]{\itshape\nouppercase\leftmark}
\fancyhead[LE, RO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot{}}

\pagestyle{theorems}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{A chapter}
\newpage
a
\end{document}
```

Corresponding heading

[image]

Comment: Please note: `\usepage[showframe]{geometry}` changed the size of the text area and margins. If you don't want this, you should either use `\usepackage{showframe}` instead of loading `geometry` or add option `pass`.

Comment: Usage of `fancyhdr` together with a KOMA-Script class is not recommended. It needs extra user work to not break several features of KOMA-Script (e.g. to respect `\chaptermarkformat`). See the warning message of KOMA-Script.

Comment: Got it. Should I open another post asking how to create that heading with a KOMA-Script class or do you have a quick fix?

Comment: Use `scrlayer-scrpage` as recommended by the warning in the `log`-file.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I posted a [new question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/481223/172923) as I'm having a few issues with `scrlayer-scrpage` package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use option `chapterprefix` if you want a chapter heading with a prefix line, that has only the formatted number:

```
\documentclass[chapterprefix]{scrbook}
\usepackage{xcolor, graphicx}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\definecolor{chaptergrey}{rgb}{0.7,0.7,0.7}

\let\raggedchapter\raggedleft
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\normalfont}
\setkomafont{chapter}{\LARGE}

\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
\scalebox{5}{\color{chaptergrey}\thechapter}%
}
\renewcommand*{\chaptermarkformat}{\thechapter\autodot\enskip}% If you don't want the chapter name in the running head.
\begin{document}
\chapter{A chapter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

There are already examples for similar chapter headings like:

- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/480247/9057
- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/298509/9057

Please avoid using `fancyhdr` with KOMA-Script classes. As the warning message tells you, using `fancyhdr` breaks several features of KOMA-Script classes. Use `scrlayer-scrpage` instead. If you want running head aligned to the inner margin and page numbers aligned to the outer margins and if the chapter titles in the running head should be without chapter numbers, you can use:

```
\renewcommand*{\chaptermarkformat}{}% If you want running heads without
                                % chapter number.

\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead*{\pagemark}% page number also on plain pages
\ohead{\headmark}
```

Comment: It works, but now the headings are 'Chapter 1 A chapter', while before they were simply  '1 A chapter'. How do I fix that?

Comment: @noibe Not with my example and KOMA-Script 3.26b, which is the [current release on CTAN, in TeX Live and MiKTeX](https://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script).

Comment: I have the same version. I found a workaround through `\makeatletter\renewcommand{\@chapapp}{}\makeatother`

Comment: @noibe After the shown redefinition of `\chapterformat` KOMA-Script cannot produce the output you are talking about. And redefining `\@chapapp` would not remove the space. So you are doing something you are not telling us. And note, `\appendix` would again redefine `\@chapapp`.

Comment: That's possible. I posted an example showing my problem in my original question.