# Customizing headings using scrlayer-scrpage

Tags: koma-script, scrbook, scrlayer-scrpage

Using the `scrbook` class, how do I customize the chapter plain pagestyle? I'd like to have the page number on the left on even pages and on the right on odd ones. Also, how do I get rid of the 'Chapter' in the headings? Here's a MWE

```
\documentclass[chapterprefix]{scrbook}
\usepackage{xcolor, graphicx, lipsum}
\definecolor{chaptergrey}{rgb}{0.7,0.7,0.7}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}

\let\raggedchapter\raggedleft
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\normalfont}
\setkomafont{chapter}{\LARGE}

\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
\scalebox{5}{\color{chaptergrey}\thechapter}%
}

\clearmainofpairofpagestyles
\lehead{\leftmark}
\rohead{\leftmark}
\lohead{\pagemark}
\rehead{\pagemark}

\begin{document}
\chapter{A chapter}
\lipsum[1-30]
\end{document}
```

Note: I can't load the `fancyhdr` package because it causes problems, and I cannot remove the `chapterprefix` class option because I need it to have the chapter title below the chapter number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I've already told in [my answer to your last question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/481211) you can manipulate the chapter number in the running head by redefining `\chaptermarkformat`. The default definition is shown in the KOMA-Script manual:

```
\newcommand*{\chaptermarkformat}{%
  \chapappifchapterprefix{\ }\thechapter\autodot\enskip}
```

`\chapappifchapterprefix{\ }` prints `\chapapp` followed by a space if option `chapterprefix` is enabled. `\chapapp` is the same like `\@chapapp`, which is `\chaptername` before `\appendix` and `\appendixname` after `\appendix`. So, if you do not want the prefix, redefine `\chaptermarkformat`  like this:

```
\renewcommand*{\chaptermarkformat}{\thechapter\autodot\endskip}
```

If you even do not like the number, just use

```
\renewcommand*{\chaptermarkformat}{}
```

As also shown in the same answer, to get automatic running heads, you have to load `scrlayer-scrpage` with option `automark`. This would use chapter titles for the even pages and section titles for the odd pages. Alternatively you can use command `\automark` and `\automark*` to influence the content of the automatic running head. See the KOMA-Script manual for more information.

If you want the running head aligned to the inner margin and the page number aligned to the outer margin, you can use `\ihead` for the running head marks and `\ohead` for the pagination marks. To add the page numbers also to the plain pages, you should use the `*`-variant. To remove the default marks from the *headings* and the *plain* page style you should use `\clearpairofpagestyles`. `\clearmainofpagestyles` only cleans up the marks from the *headings* pagestyle of the pair.

So

```
\documentclass[chapterprefix]{scrbook}
\usepackage{xcolor, graphicx, blindtext}
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\definecolor{chaptergrey}{rgb}{0.7,0.7,0.7}

\let\raggedchapter\raggedleft
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\normalfont}
\setkomafont{chapter}{\LARGE}

\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
\scalebox{5}{\color{chaptergrey}\thechapter}%
}

\renewcommand*{\chaptermarkformat}{}% If you want running heads without
                                % chapter number.
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead*{\pagemark}% page number also on plain pages
\ohead{\headmark}

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

will result in:

[image: page 1 and 2]
[image: page 3 and 4]

and

```
\documentclass[chapterprefix]{scrbook}
\usepackage{xcolor, graphicx, blindtext}
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\definecolor{chaptergrey}{rgb}{0.7,0.7,0.7}

\let\raggedchapter\raggedleft
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\normalfont}
\setkomafont{chapter}{\LARGE}

\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
\scalebox{5}{\color{chaptergrey}\thechapter}%
}

\renewcommand*{\chaptermarkformat}{\thechapter\autodot\enskip}% only number,
                                % opional dot and white space, but no prefix
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead*{\pagemark}% page number also on plain pages
\ohead{\headmark}

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

results in:

[image: page 1 and 2]
[image: page 3 and 4]

Comment: A very good and instructive answer (in my opinion)